# How can I make a Like/Dislike button in an Asp .net core web site like a blog?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to web development with .net core mvc and am building a web application that works much like Wordpress.

Basically I am building a site in which articles will be posted by an administrator and the user will come to read these articles there.
I must now make a "like" button and a "dislike" button to allow the reader to give his opinion. The process is very simple for the moment, I created an Article table in my database and I added two columns to it: NumberOfLikes and NumberOfDislikes.
Then I added the two buttons on the article page. What I want now is like I said, to make sure that when we click on the like button, it adds +1 to NumberOfLikes and conversely when we click on the dislike button, it adds +1 a NumbreOfDislikes.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this feature that's why I'm turning to you for help.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

this is the `Article Model class` class:

```cs
public class Article{
    public long Id{ get; set; }
    public long NumberOfLikes{ get; set; }
    public long NumberOfDisLikes{ get; set; }
}
```

This is the `Index` action in `ArticleController.cs`

```cs
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(long id)
        {
            Article article = await _context.Articles
                                            .Where(a => a.Id == id)
                                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (article == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            ArticleViewModel model = new ArticleViewModel();
            model.Article = article;

            await GetDataForLayout(_context);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return View(model);
        }
```

and in the `/Article/Index.cshtml` View we have two buttons like this:

```html
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-success like-article">
            <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>
            <span>Like &nbsp; @article.NumberOfLikes</span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger dislike-article">
            <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i>
            <span>DisLike &nbsp; @article.NumberOfDisLikes</span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

I don't know if putting `@article.NumberOfLikes` can allow me to see the updated values but it's the values that I want there.
So I Want to click on these buttons and update values of `NumberOfLikes/NumberOfDislikes` of the article without changing the page or refresh it and make the changes visible by the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  to replace buttons,try to pass id and like or dislike to action,then update the article.Here is a demo with efcore:

Article:

```
public class Article
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfLikes { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfDislikes { get; set; }

    }
```

Actions:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {

            return View(_context.Article.ToList());

        }
        public async Task<List<Article>> Edit(int id, bool like)
    {
        var article = await _context.Article.FindAsync(id);
        if (like)
        {
            article.NumberOfLikes++;
        }
        else {
            article.NumberOfDislikes++;
        }
        _context.Update(article);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return _context.Article.ToList();

    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
    @model IEnumerable<WebApplication_efcore.Models.Article>
    <<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NumberOfLikes)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NumberOfDislikes)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody1">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumberOfLikes)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumberOfDislikes)
            </td>
            <td>
                <button onclick="Edit(@item.Id,true)">Like</button>
                <button onclick="Edit(@item.Id,false)">Dislike</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    function Edit(id,like)
    {
       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: { id: id, like: like },
                url: 'Edit',
       }).done(function (result) {
                var html=""
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
                {
                    html += '<tr><td>' + result[i].id + '</td><td>' + result[i].numberOfLikes + '</td><td>' + result[i].numberOfDislikes + '</td><td><button onclick="Edit(' + result[i].id + ',true)">Like</button><button onclick="Edit(' + result[i].id +',false)">Dislike</button></td></tr>'
           }
           document.getElementById("tbody1").innerHTML = html;
            });
    }
</script>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Yiyi for answering. This a good idea but it doesn't do exactly what I want. I'll put an edit and you should understand. In fact I want to increase the values without refresh the page.

Comment: You mean you don't want to refresh the updated value in the view,only want to update it in db?

Comment: I want to refresh these values in the view and in the Db but without change the page or refresh it.

Comment: If you want to change the value in the view,we will usually refresh the view.Because change the html code will be more complex.

Comment: I read that with AJAX we could make changes to the DOM without reloading the whole page. but i don't know how it works.

Comment: Yes,but you need to replace html code after ajax.

Comment: Okay, can you help me first to make sure that when I click on the button it updates the Database? without making any change on the page. And so I will see how to improve it with AJAX.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your availability. I have adapted your solution to my situation and it works very well.
Now do you have any idea so that each user is limited to a single like / dislike