# I want to separate a single controller action into multiple controller actions in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have website that relies on cards to display data. `Details` action points to the data to be displayed. Like and Dislike buttons inside my Details page relies on the pointed data. I tried using if statements to implement Like and Dislike function but only Like function works while Dislike function doesn't. I want to create separate action for both `Like` and `Dislike`. Here is my code:

`DetailController.cs-`

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Detail(int id, bool like, bool dislike)
{
    Post post = await _postInterface.GetByIdAsync(id);

    // Likes
    if (like)
    {
        post.Like += 1;

        _context.Update(post);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    // Dislikes
    if (dislike)
    {
        post.Dislike += 1;

        _context.Update(post);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    return View(post);
}
```

---

I can see why my dislike function doesn't work.

`Details.cshtml-`

```html
<div class="btn-group" role="group" id="UserVotes" pt-1">

    <!-- Like -->
    <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="Likebtn" name="Votegroup[]" autocomplete="off">
    <a asp-controller="Post" asp-action="Detail" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm shadow-none" for="Likebtn" onclick="Like(@Model.Id, true)">@Model.Like Likes</a>

    <!-- Dislike -->
    <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="Dislikebtn" name="Votegroup[]" autocomplete="off">
    <a asp-controller="Post" asp-action="Detail" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm shadow-none" for="Dislikebtn" onclick="Dislike(@Model.Id, true)">@Model.Dislike Dislikes</a>

</div>
```

---

`like-dislike.js`

```js
function Like(id, like) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { id: id, like: like },
        url: 'Like',
    }).done(function (result) {
        var html = ""
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            html += '<tr><td>' + result[i].id + '</td><td>' + result[i].Like + '</td><td><button onclick="Like(' + result[i].id + ',true)">Like</button></td></tr>'
        }
        document.getElementById("UserVotes").innerHTML = html;
    });
}

function Disike(id, dislike) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { id: id, dislike: dislike },
        url: 'Disike',
    }).done(function (result) {
        var html = ""
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            html += '<tr><td>' + result[i].id + '</td><td>' + result[i].Dislike + '</td><td><button onclick="Dislike(' + result[i].id + ',true)">Dislikes</button></td></tr>'
        }
        document.getElementById("UserVotes").innerHTML = html;
    });
}
```

---

##### The issue has been resolved. I have also posted my solution. Thank you

Comment: You need to provide more details. Offhand, I see now reason why your `if` wouldn't work for Like or Dislike, but be that as it may, the way you would implement Dislike in a separate controller action would probably be very much the same way you did it for Like.

Comment: I have updated the code  :)

Comment: Ya, why not? You can write a "Like" action with the like action implementation. `public async Task<IActionResult> Like(int id) { ... }`. Same goes to "Dislike".

Comment: @YongShun I tried what you suggested but it doesn't work as the `Like` function doesn't know what data to point to. I have cards with Id- 1,2,...10 but it always points to Id- 0. That's why I want to use my detail action as it can points to my cards Id

Comment: I suspect that you are not passing the `Id` to the controller action. Add `asp-route-id="@Model.Id"` in the `<a>` element.

Comment: `onclick="Like(@Model.Id, true)"`, seems like you have JS function to do something before sending the request?

Comment: I was trying to use Ajax so make make sure only the button value changes every time it is clicked without refreshing the page. I got the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68629677/20763759).  Not much success tho. I have updated my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256053/discussion-between-znaxnor-and-yong-shun).

Answer (score 2):

The Detail function you have 3 arguments:

```
Detail(int id, bool like, bool dislike)
```

Yet you call it like this with 2 args:

```
Like(@Model.Id, true)   
Dislike(@Model.Id, true)
```

> but only Like function works while Dislike function doesn't

Option 1: Can you try this instead:

```
Like(@Model.Id, true, false)   
Dislike(@Model.Id, false, true)
```

Option 2: Make your function simpler:

```
Detail(int id, bool like)
{
  if (like) {

  }
  else //if (!like)
  {

  }
```

Option 3: Have two methods (Like & Dislike) as suggested in the comments.

Comment: I have updated my view as the comment above suggested and the Id points to correct data now, but I would like to remain on the same page after the action is over without creating a separate view for my Like action.

Comment: Yeah it would to have been good if you provded that additional information before I answered. To keep on the same page instead of `returning a View(post);`, instead `return RedirectToAction("YourCurrentAction");`

Comment: I tried `return RedirectToAction("Detail");` but it returns error `Model.get returned null.` as it cannot point to the exact detail page Id I was previously on.

Comment: I got it. I used `string url = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();` and `return Redirect(url);`

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

`DetailController.cs-`

```cs
// Details
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Detail(int id)
{
    Post post = await _postInterface.GetByIdAsync(id);

    return View(post);
}

// Like
public async Task<IActionResult> Like(int id)
{
    Post post = await _postInterface.GetByIdAsync(id);

    post.Like++;

    _context.Update(post);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    string url = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();

    return Redirect(url);
}

// Dislike
public async Task<IActionResult> Dislike(int id)
{
    Post post = await _postInterface.GetByIdAsync(id);

    post.Dislike++;

    _context.Update(post);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    string url = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();

    return Redirect(url);
}
```

---

`Details.cshtml-`

```html
 <div class="btn-group" role="group" id="UserVotes" pt-1">

     <!-- Like -->
     <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="Likebtn" name="Votegroup[]" autocomplete="off">
     <a asp-controller="Post" asp-action="Like" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm shadow-none" for="Likebtn" onclick="Like(@Model.Id, true)">@Model.Like Likes</a>

     <!-- Dislike -->
     <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="Dislikebtn" name="Votegroup[]" autocomplete="off">
     <a asp-controller="Post" asp-action="Dislike" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm shadow-none" for="Dislikebtn">@Model.Dislike Dislikes</a>

 </div>
```